# With click, navigate to another page and open a div hidden by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages. Lets call the first page `index.html` and the second page `products.html`.

On `products.html` I have a div that is hidden unless the user clicks a button to reveal it, as shown below:

### products.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.product-highlight').hide();
  
  $('a[href$=shoes').click(function() {
    $('#shoes').show();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
  <a href="#shoes">Show Shoes</a>
</div>

<div class="product-highlight" id="shoes">
  <p>These are the shoes</p>
</div>
```

Now on my `index.html` I have a link that should directly lead to the shoes tab and have it revealed.

So far all I know how to do is:

### index.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('a[href$=shoes]').click(function() {
    
    window.location.href= 'http://sample.com/products.php/';
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#shoes">Take me to the shoes</a>
```

Comment: What's your question? You asking how to run some code when the page loads? Looks like you already know how to do that, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget) pseudo-class. For this define next CSS rules:

```css
#shoes {
    display: none; /* hide by default */
}
#shoes:target, /* and show either if class show is present (on click) */
#shoes.show {  /* or location hash matches id "shoes" */
    display: block;
}
```

and in JS you would add class `show`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.product-highlight').hide();

  $('a[href$=shoes').click(function() {
    $('#shoes').addClass('show');
  });

});
```

When redirecting from index page you would also need to set a hash `#shoes`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a[href$=shoes]').click(function() {

    window.location.href= 'http://sample.com/products.php/#shoes';

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One strategy:

- Have index.html link to http://sample.com/products.php#shoes (a plain old `<a href="/products.php#shoes">` will do, no need for a jQuery click event here.)
- Have products.php check document.location.hash for '#shoes' and trigger `$('#shoes').show()` if present.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's .click() without any arguments, fires the click event on that element, so in the very simplest of solutions, if the user's coming to the products page by clicking the shoes link, add a query string to the end (/products.php/?q=shoes)

and then in the javascript in the product page, if it sees that there's a product needed, it can auto trigger the click event on whatever element on that page you're supposed to click on to make it show up.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery) question has an example of how to pull parameters out of a URL with jQuery.

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Location hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp)

At your link in **index.html**

```
<a href="products.html#shoes">Take me to the shoes</a>
```

And in your **products.html** script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.product-highlight').hide();

  $('a[href$=shoes]').click(function() {
    $('#shoes').show();
  });

  if ( location.hash != 0 && location.hash == '#shoes' ){
     $('a[href$=shoes]').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

When you have a `location.hash` target to an element called `#shoes` in your **products.html**, the script will trigger the event button `'click'` to reveal your awesome shoes.

Answer (score 1):

Add one line of code as indicated below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.product-highlight').hide();
  
  $('a[href$=shoes').click(function() {
    $('#shoes').show();
  });

  // add this line...
  $(window.location.hash).show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
  <a href="#shoes">Show Shoes</a>
</div>

<div class="product-highlight" id="shoes">
  <p>These are the shoes</p>
</div>
```

Go to http://codepen.io/palermo4/pen/KpoGdY to test